# Elasticsearch custom scoring function test null date values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

I can't find anywhere examples of how to test null values in ES custom scoring functions. 
According to the doc the scripts are in groovy, according to the log the script is evaluated in painless, but even with that I'm left puzzled by some errors

```
"script":"doc['response_rate'].value ? (doc['response_rate'].value + 1) : 0",
"lang":"painless",
"caused_by":{
  "type":"wrong_method_type_exception",
  "reason":"cannot convert MethodHandle(Doubles)double to (Object)boolean"}}}]
```

This seems to say I'm trying to cas a double to boolean and raises, but I need to test for non-null values.

How should I write my scoring script ?

EDIT : I have understood that in painless I cannot use the ternary `? :` operator, so I must write explicitely `doc['xx'].value != null`. However, this seems to produce weird results for dates that were indexed with null values. It would seem that in painless the value is NOT null (although it is indeed `null` in the json when I `GET /_search` it) and the following does not work

```
"script":"(doc['unavailable_until'].value != null) ? 1 : 0"
```

and always seem to return 0 (as if the null date was actually not null). I have seen some people reporting something some weird default date, in this case how can I compare this date to something like Date.now ?

Comment: Null is represented as NA in Elasticsearch but you can specify your own in mapping

Comment: @sramalingam24 is it the same behavior with dates in painless ? I seem to have problems especially with dates now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why I couldn't find [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/modules-scripting-expression.html#_date_field_api) before...

Basically, one can just call `.empty` to check for null values. Works with dates too

```
"script":"doc['unavailable_until'].empty ? 1 : 0",
```